# Truncate database automatically without event scheduler?

Tags: php, mysql

My host ([blueangelhost.com](http://blueangelhost.com)) claims that I can't use the event scheduler because it takes up too many resources. I have access to cron jobs in cPanel, but I've tried and they don't seem to work.

So, my question: Is there any kind of efficient PHP code that will automatically truncate a MySQL table in a database?

Comment: if you can't get cron working, then not really... php isn't a job scheduler, and shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm sure the cron jobs work. You should try to figure out why *you* can't get them to work.

Comment: If the cronjob won't work, but you can run the script manually - you need to check the file permissions.

Comment: cron job needs to execute a shell script (bash usually) which then runs php -q yourfiletotruncate.php.  if you want to do it that route or you can run a truncate directly across the command line something like `mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME < "TRUNCATE TABLENAME"`

Comment: What do you mean by "*automatically truncate*"?  When would you want such truncation to automatically occur?

Comment: @eggyal every 30 minutes to clear a user inputted list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it needs to be automatic, or at a specific time, not really. But you could have your website trigger the script when someone gets on it, here's the approach you could use:

On a script that is run on every page (header, menu,footer, layout):

```
Check in DB or file, the date of the last truncate;
If the date is yesterday, run the truncate;
Change DB or file and put current date;
```

This way, it will execute once a day. But never at the same time, and not if no one walks on your website for a whole day.

Comment: Thanks im probably just gonna leave my host. Do you know of any good hosts that allow evrtgthing? Blueangelbost had unlimitef shared hosting for like $5 for 6 months. Unlimited bandwith and such. They just dont let you use somr cpanel features.